# php qr code is not displaying correctly

Tags: cakephp, qr-code

I'm using CakePHP 3.4 framework for my application and [endroid/qrcode](https://github.com/endroid/QrCode) generator.

In controller, I have used

```
use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode;

$qrCode = new QrCode();
$qrCode
    ->setText('Life is too short to be generating QR codes')
    ->setSize(300)
    ->setPadding(10)
    ->setErrorCorrection('high')
    ->setForegroundColor(array('r' => 0, 'g' => 0, 'b' => 0, 'a' => 0))
    ->setBackgroundColor(array('r' => 255, 'g' => 255, 'b' => 255, 'a' => 0))
    ->setLabel('Scan the code')
    ->setLabelFontSize(16)
    ->setImageType(QrCode::IMAGE_TYPE_PNG)
;
$this->set(compact('qrCode'));
```

and in view

```
header('Content-Type: '.$qrCode->getContentType());
$qrCode->render(); ?>
```

But this is rendering as

[image]

What could be the issue, it is not showing qr image?

Comment: Are you just rendering only the image? If so, you should use the Response object to return the image from the controller.

Comment: creating response as per documentation giver error `Response class not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Controller method only returns the QR Code image, you should be fine, adding the following code to your Controller.

**Edit:** Checked the Docs of the Library you are using. You gotta use a `Writer` as per the docs. Please read them. Untested:

```
use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode;
use Endroid\QrCode\Writer\PngWriter;
...
$response = $this->response;

$response = $response->withType($qrCode->getContentType(PngWriter::class))
    ->withStringBody($qrCode->writeString(PngWriter::class));

// Return response object – you won't have to have a View for this method 
return $response;

// $this->set(...) from your code is obsolete
```

Sending headers in the View seems wrong since it is a Controller task.

**Edit:** You could then use the controller method as an image source, i. e.:

```
<img src="/path/to/your/controller/action" alt="QR Code here">
```

If you want the QR Code to display inside a view of this method instead of returning the image, you could either:

**a) write the generated QR Code to your filesystem as an image file**

Use the `Endroid\QrCode\QrCode::writeFile()` method of the library instead of returning the `Response` object.

**b) use a Data URI as written in the Docs**

```
$writer = new DataUriWriter($qrCode);
$dataUri = $writer->writeString();
```

I really wonder if you even read the [Docs](https://github.com/endroid/QrCode#usage).

Comment: `withStringBody()` ;-)

Comment: Thanks @ndm – did not notice this one. ;)

Comment: Thanks @Mary you said, I don't need to have a view for this method. But I want to display QR only on the view. ie., on call of `qrcode()` in `qrcode.ctp` view and in `qrcode()` response is created